# how to clear a picture content control with macro in ms word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have created a form where the user has the option to reset (clear) the form. I was able to clear everything from the form (textbox's, combobox's & checkboxes), but not sure how to clear a picture if one was inserted without deleting the entire option. I've tried using the bookmark method,however, with not success. the bookmark is selected then delete. Which cause the code not to recognize the Inlineshape (hence - Run-time error '5941 "the requested member of the collection does not exist".

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("picture").Select
Selection.InlineShapes(1).Delete
Selection.InsertAfter ""
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code makes no mention of content controls, however

```
Dim oCC As ContentControl
Set oCC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Picture1").Item(1)
If oCC.Range.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then oCC.Range.InlineShapes(1).Delete
```

where 'Picture1' is the title of the picture content control, should do the trick.